# Use a cursor to run a stored procedure based on parameter values in a table in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table `JOBIDS` with this structure

```
JOBID (uniqueidentifyer) 
Reportname (varchar(500))
```

and sample data:

```
JOBID                                   | REPORTNAME
----------------------------------------+---------------------------
9B444967-B7FA-440C-9313-739724D95DBF    | RUNNINGREPORT_ADM
8W495317-12FA-MH58-9233-657332D95RTD    | EmployeeId_TrainingReport
```

I would like assistance with a Cursor to select "JOBID" from my table [JOBIDS] and run the stored procedure shown below using the unique identifiers as the parameter simultaneously:

```sql
EXEC dbo.sp_rerun_job N'xxx' -- 'xxx' to be replaced by the jobId in [JOBIDS] table
```

That way all reports could be rerun based on the JobIds linked to them

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the documentation on `CURSOR`s that explains just how to use them?

Answer (score 0):

The following should be it if I understand your database structure correctly.

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50)


DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR


SELECT reportname 
FROM JOBSIDS 

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name



WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
       EXEC dbo.sp_rerun_job @name

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: If you use a cursor variable you don't need to close or deallocate. And `FAST_FORWARD` is usually best